# Start WebSocket on Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, websocket

Need to start the (PHP)WebSocket on my Ubuntu server. its a working script at least on my PC (using WAMP server). Here is the code

```
<?PHP
    include('php_web_socket.php')
    $socket = new php_web_socket();
    $socket->wsStartServer('127.0.0.1', 30001);
?>
```

I'm executing this php file by using the following command

```
php /var/www/html/server/index.php
```

But the WS connection never open.

For reference, 
I'm using the following script http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/05/chat-using-websocket-php-socket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making a mistake. Look the IP 127.0.0.1 - Localhost

lets allow the remote connection from rest of the world and change it to 0.0.0.0 and problem resolved!